# What are the different parts in (pr raw-object)?

Tags: debugging, clojure

```
(pr +)
;=> #object[clojure.core$_PLUS_ 0x4e648e99 "clojure.core$_PLUS_@4e648e99"]
```

With more complex examples, this seems to be a consistent pattern:

```
#object[namespace$symbol addr "namespace$symbol@addr"]
```

What's the purpose of the third element here?  When would it not follow this pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular format is produced by the `clojure.core/print-tagged-object` function (private to `clojure.core`) which certain implementation of `clojure.core/print-method` delegate to. Other implementations of `print-method` don't use `print-tagged-object` and produce different representations – for example Clojure's built-in data structures tend to be representable as Clojure literals.

The elements of the vector signify the following:

1. The first element is the class of the object.

   Clojure functions are instances of classes whose names are derived from the namespaces they are defined in:

   ```
   (class +)
   ;= clojure.core$_PLUS_
   ```
2. The second element is the identity hash code of the object as determined by

   ```
   (System/identityHashCode x)
   ```
3. The final element is the result of calling `print-method` on an ancillary value associated with the object, which for objects that use the `#object[…]` representation will tend to boil down to a `toString` call, although there are some exceptions:

   ```
   (prn (atom {}))
   ;; #object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x565f390 {:status :ready, :val {}}]

   (str (atom {}))
   ;= "clojure.lang.Atom@311bf055"
   ```

   This particular behaviour is explained by this snippet from the implementation:

   ```
   ;; /src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj L410-411 (as of right now)
   (defmethod print-method clojure.lang.IDeref [o ^Writer w]
     (print-tagged-object o (deref-as-map o) w))
   ```

   `{:status :ready, :val {}}` comes from the `deref-as-map` call; `deref-as-map` is defined immediately above.

See the remainder of [`/src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f76b343d917532d0b2e1397587e3fdefdd5bd166/src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj) for details (link to current tip of the master branch).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can provide such a defmethod for all functions?

Comment: @SeanAllred The definition of "a function" in Clojure is not completely straightforward, as there are many function-like built-in types (`fn` functions, multimethods, vectors, maps, sets). So, you'd have to settle on a definition and implement `print-method` for the appropriate types, and then possibly use `prefer-method` to resolve conflicts (e.g. implementing `print-method` for `c.l.IFn` makes vectors unprintable one of the applicable methods is selected using `prefer-method`). Note that libraries definitely shouldn't do that sort thing, and I'd be wary of doing it even in application code.

Comment: For reference: [clojure-emacs/cider-nrepl#268](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider-nrepl/pull/268) ([gitter conversation](https://gitter.im/clojure-emacs/cider?at=562281fe5560144738d6684c))